# data structures that can be used for making an english dictionary

Tags: python, c, data-structures, hashmap

So I have a dataset of words with their parts of speech and their meanings in a csv file. I have sorted it into three columns. But I am confused for which data structure to use. I want the dictionary to display the meanings as well as the parts of speech. I made a hashmap which is as follows:

```
{'A':['abaca',
 'abacinate',
 'abacination',
 'abaciscus',
 'abacist',
 'aback',
 'abactinal',
 'abaction',
 'abactor',
 'abaculi'....],'B':...}
```

Now if a word is given should I use a tree to display the meanings or any other data structure?

Comment: Have you tried to do so ?

Comment: it really depends on what data you need, and how you want to access it. For starters, why are you using the first letter in your data structure at all?

Comment: every alphabet has a different csv file. and so I generated this.

Comment: Is this supposed to be Python or C?  The answer will be very different for each.

Comment: You already know the data structure you want to build. All you need to do is find a Hashmap implementation in C.

Comment: You can implement tries data structure.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what exactly is the problem and what you have to do after creating a data-structure.

But try converting your existing dictionary to dictionary of dictionaries. Where the second dictionary will have the meanings/POS in it.

{'A':['apple':['a fruit', ' red colored object'....] , 'aeroplane':['a flying object',....],...,'B':[.....],....}